# Confusión buenas prácticas de programación

Tags: java, java-swing, jmenubar

estoy haciendo en java la interfaz de la calculadora de Windows 7, y me surge una pregunta al hacer los menús. ¿Qué es mejor, usar el mismo objeto para dar nombre y/o propiedades a los menús, o crear un objeto para cada menú? No sé si fui claro, en este fragmento de código estoy usando un objeto llamado jMenu y lo utilizo para crear diferentes menús y agregarlos al JMenuBar.

```
JMenu jMenu = new JMenu("Ver");
        jMenu.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        jMenu.setBackground(Color.red);
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Estándar                                          Alt+1"));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Científica                                         Alt+2"));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("*    Programador                                  Alt+3"));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Estadísticas                                    Alt+4"));
        jMenu.addSeparator();
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Historial                                         Alt+H"));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Número de dígitos en grupo                "));
        jMenu.addSeparator();
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("*    Básicas                                        Ctrl+F4"));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Conversión de unidades            Ctrl+U"));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Cálculo de Fecha                          Ctrl+E"));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Hojas de cálculo                                  >"));
        this.add(jMenu);

        jMenu = new JMenu("Edición");
        jMenu.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Copiar         Ctrl+C"));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("     Pegar          Ctrl+V"));
        this.add(jMenu);

        jMenu = new JMenu("Ayuda");
        jMenu.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("Ver la ayuda                        F1"));
        jMenu.addSeparator();
        jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem("Acerca de la Calculadora"));
        this.add(jMenu);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke)) para la clase `JMenuItem` (supongo que la extiendes en tu clase `MyJMenuItem`), hay un método llamado `setAccelerator` que te podría ahorrar el uso de los 'shortcut' (ALT+1, ALT+2...) sin tener que hacerlos manualmente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La verdad es que los objetos los creas igual, estes o no reutilizando la variable para referenciarlos.

```
JMenu jMenu1 = new JMenu("Ver");
this.add(jMenu1);
JMenu jMenu2 = new JMenu("Edicion");
this.add(jMenu2);
```

Es lo mismo que:

```
JMenu jMenu = new JMenu("Ver");
this.add(jMenu);
jMenu = new JMenu("Edicion");
this.add(jMenu);
```

Ahora bien, sobre mejores practicas, podrias seguir el principio DRY (en español, *no te repitas a ti mismo*) y evitar duplicidad de codigo.

Por ejemplo, podrias decidir crear un metodo que reciba un listado de subMenus a crear, como:

```
private JMenu crearMenu(String nombre, String... subs) {
    JMenu jMenu = new JMenu(nombre);
    jMenu.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    for (String sub : subs) {
        if (sub.isEmpty()) {
            jMenu.addSeparator();
        } else {
            jMenu.add(new MyJMenuItem(sub));
        }
    }
    return jMenu;
}
```

Y luego simplemente agregarlo con todos los parametros:

```
this.add(
        crearMenu("Ver",
                "Estándar",
                "Científica",
                "Programador",
                "Estadísticas",
                "",
                "Historial"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay una confusión.

Cuando escribes `JMenu jmenu;` no estás creando un objeto. Simplemente creas una referencia, una referencia vacía ya que no está ligada a ningún objeto.

Con `new JMenu("Ver");` sí estás creando un objeto tipo JMenu. Pero con sólo crearlo no basta ya que, como no tienes ninguna referencia a este objeto, es imposible usarlo y solo estás desperdiciando espacio en memoria (Hasta que venga el recolector de basura).

`jmenu = new JMenu("Ver");` ahora sí, creaste un objeto y lo asignaste a la referencia `jmenu`.

Cada que haces

```
jmenu = new JMenu("Ver");
jmenu = new JMenu("Edición");
jmenu = new JMenu("Ayuda");
```

Estas usando la misma referencia para otros objetos.

Pero nota, que al asignarle un objeto nuevo a la referencia `jmenu`, el objeto anterior pierde ésta referencia. Es decir, al momento de ejecutar `jmenu = new JMenu("Ayuda");`, ésta referencia `jmenu` apunta únicamente al menú de "Ayuda". Los menús de "Edición" y "Ver" ya sólo son accesibles desde una colección dentro de tu JMenuBar.

**Contestando a tu pregunta**, así como lo haces es la manera óptima aunque no hace mucha diferencia.

Cada vez que agregas el objeto al `JMenuBar` le estás dando 2 referencias al mismo objeto (una es `jmenu` y la otra es a través del `JMenuBar`). Por lo que puedes reutilizar la referencia `jmenu` para distintos objetos.

Si usaras una referencia nueva por cada objeto ocuparías un poco más de espacio en memoria (por lo menos hasta que ese método/función en donde creas los menús termine, en caso de haberlos creado en `Main()` tus referencias seguirán vivas ocupando unos cuantos bytes de memoria).